# Woud you please check some steps in proof I tried of Trace Theorem from Evans book?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, partial-derivative, sobolev-spaces, change-of-variable

I tried to open every step of trace theorem from the book of Evans, but I still wondering if is everything right?

**Thanks in advance.**

**Trace Theorem:** Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be open, bounded and $\partial \Omega$ of class $C^1$ and $1\leq p< \infty$. Then there exists a bounded linear operator
$$T:W^{1, p}(\Omega)\rightarrow L^p(\partial \Omega)$$
such that

1. If $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ then $Tu=u_{|{\partial \Omega}}$.
2. There exists $C=C(p, \Omega)>0$ such that
   $$\|Tu\|_{L^p(\partial \Omega)}\leq C \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)},\qquad \forall u\in { W^{1,p}(\Omega)}.$$

**MY ATTEMPT:**

> **Step 1**

Assume first $u\in C^{1}(\overline{\Omega})$. We will proceed as in the first part of the proof of the extension theorem. Thus, initially suppose that $x_0\in \partial \Omega$ and that $\partial \Omega$ is *flat* near $x_0$, lying in the plane $\{x_n=0\}$. Let us choose an open ball $B_r(x_0)$ such that $B_{\frac{r}{2}(x_0)} \subset B_r(x_0)$.
\begin{align}
B_{r}^{+}(x_0)&:= B\cap \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}\subset\overline{\Omega}\\
B_{\frac{r}{2}}^{+}(x_0)&:= B_{\frac{r}{2}}(x_0) \cap \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n} \subset B_{r}^{+}(x_0)
 \end{align}
Let us denote by $\Gamma :=\partial B_{\frac{r}{2}}^{+}(x_0) \cap \partial \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$.

[image]

[image]

Of course
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\partial \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}\supset \Gamma
\end{align}
Choosing that
\begin{align}\tag{2}
  \varphi \in C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega) \implies \varphi\equiv 0,  \forall x \notin \mathscr{supp} \Omega
\end{align}
satisfying
\begin{align}
0\leq \varphi &\leq 1 \in B_{r}^{+}(x_0)\tag{3}\\
\varphi&=1 \in B_{\frac{r}{2}}^{+}(x_0)\tag{4}
\end{align}

\begin{align} \tag{5}
&\text{And since}\; \Omega = B_{r}^{+}(x_0)\; \text{then}\; \partial \Omega \; \text{ is a hypersurfaceof class}\; C^1
\end{align}

We can apply the divergence theorem to obtain

\begin{align}\tag{6}
\int_{\Gamma} |u|^p d\sigma_x & \overset{4}{=} \int_{\Gamma} \varphi |u|^p d\sigma_x\\
&\overset{1}{\leq}\int_{\partial \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}} \varphi |u|^p dx\\
&\overset{5}{=}-\int_{\mathbb{R}_{n}^{+}} \left(\varphi |u|^p \right) _{x_n} dx 
\end{align}

Where in equality in ${{5}}$ we use the divergence theorem taking $\eta =(0, 0, ..., -1)$ and $F=(0,0, ..., 0, \varphi |u|^p)$, and we obtained that
\begin{align}
\int_{\partial \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}} F\eta d\sigma_{x}&=\int_{\partial \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}} ( 0,0, ..., 0, \varphi |u|^p)(0, 0, ..., -1) d\sigma_{x}\\
&=- \int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}} \left(\varphi |u|^p\right)_{x_n} dx
\end{align}
Now differentiating the last expression in ${{6}}$, we have

\begin{align} \tag{7}
&-\int_{\mathbb{R}_{n}^{+}} \varphi_{x_n} |u|^p dx - \int_{\mathbb{R}_{n}^{+}} {\operatorname{sgn}}(u) u_{x_n} p |u|^{p-1}\varphi  dx\\
&\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}_{n}^{+}} |\varphi_{x_n}| |u|^p dx +\int_{\mathbb{R}_{n}^{+}} |p{\operatorname{sgn}}(u) \varphi u_{x_n}| |u|^{p-1} dx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}_{n}^{+}} |\varphi_{x_n}| |u|^p dx +p\int_{\mathbb{R}_{n}^{+}} |\varphi u_{x_n}| |u|^{p-1} dx
\end{align}

Let's solve separately the integrals that appear in the last equality above. Hence for the first statement we have:
\begin{align}\tag{8}
\int_{\mathbb{R}_{n}^{+}} |\varphi_{x_n}| |u|^p dx
&\leq \int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)} |\varphi_{x_n}| |u|^p dx\\
&\leq \|\nabla \varphi\|_{\infty} \int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)} |u|^p  dx\\
&\leq C_1 \int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)} |u|^p  dx
\end{align}

Now note that in the last statement of ${{7}}$, applying Young's inequality to $|u_{x_n}|$ and $|u|^{p-1}$, considering $\frac{1}{ p}+ \frac{1}{p'}=1$ where $p'= \frac{p}{p-1}$, we have

\begin{align}\tag{9}
p\int_{\mathbb{R}_{n}^{+}} |\varphi u_{x_n}| |u|^{p-1} dx &\leq p\int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)} |u_{x_n}| |u|^{p-1} dx\\
&\leq p\int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)}\left( \frac{1}{p}|u_{x_n}|^p +\frac{1}{p'} |u|^{(p-1)p'} \right)dx\\
&\leq \int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)}|\nabla u|^p  dx+\frac{p}{p'} \int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)} |u|^p dx
\end{align}
Hence, replacing the equations ${{8}}$ and ${{9}}$ into the equation $(7)$ it follows that

\begin{align}\tag{10}
&\int_{\mathbb{R}_{n}^{+}} |\varphi_{x_n}| |u|^p dx +p\int_{\mathbb{R}_{n}^{+}} |\varphi u_{x_n}| |u|^{p-1} dx\\
&\leq C_1 \int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)} |u|^p  dx + \int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)}|\nabla u|^p  dx+\frac{p}{p'} \int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)} |u|^p dx\\
&\leq C_2\left( \int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)} |u|^p  dx + \int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)}|\nabla u |^p  dx+ \int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)} |u|^p dx\right)\\
&\leq C_3\left( \int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)}|\nabla u|^p  dx+ \int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)} | u|^p dx\right)
\end{align}

Where $C_2:=\max\{1, C_1, \frac{p}{p'}\}$ and $C_3:=\max\{2, C_2\}$. \ Therefore, it follows from ${{10}}$ and the above that
\begin{align} \tag{11}
\int_{\Gamma} |u|^p d\sigma_x \leq \tilde{C}\left( \int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)}|\nabla u|^p  dx+ \int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)} |u|^p dx \right)
\end{align}
That is,
\begin{align} \tag{12}
\|u\|_{L^p(\Gamma)}^{p} \leq \tilde{C}\|u\|_{W{1,p}(B_{r}^{+}(x_0 ))}^{p}
\end{align}

> **Step 2**

If $x_0\in \partial \Omega$, and $\partial \Omega$ is not *flat* near $x_0$, we can *straighten out* the boundary near $x_0$ in order to obtain the same estimate as in step 1.

As $\partial \Omega$ is compact there exist finitely many points $x^{0}_{j}\in \partial \Omega$ (we are going to denote only by $X_0$) and open subsets $\Omega_j\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\partial \Omega\subset \displaystyle\mathop{\cup}_{ j=1}^{k}\Omega_j$.
With this, define

\begin{align}\tag{13}
\psi_j:\Omega_j\rightarrow \overline{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)}
\end{align}

More specifically, given that $\Omega$ is $C^1$, it follows from the definition of class $C^1$ boundary that for every point $x^{0}_{j}\in \partial \Omega$ there exist $r>0$ and a function $\gamma:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ also of class $C^1$, such that

\begin{align}
\tag{14}
\Omega \cap \Omega_j=&\{x\in {U\subset \mathbb{R}^n: x_n > \gamma(x_1, ... , x_{n-1}) }\}\\
\partial\Omega \cap \Omega_j=&\{x\in \overline{U}\subset\mathbb{R}^n: x_n = \gamma(x_1, . .., x_{n-1})\}
\end{align}

Hence $13$ must satisfy

\begin{align}\tag{15}
\psi_j(\Omega\cap \Omega_j)&= B_{r}^{+}(x_0)\\
\psi_j(\partial \Omega \cap \Omega_j) &= \partial B_{r}^{+}(x_0)\cap \partial \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}
\end{align}

Define
\begin{align}\tag{16}
\Gamma_j:= \psi_{j}^{-1}(\Gamma).
\end{align}

[image]

Therefore, there exist finitely many points $x^{0}_{j}\in \partial \Omega$ and closed subsets $\Gamma_j\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$, such that

\begin{align}\tag{17}
\partial \Omega= \mathop{\bigcup}_{j=1}^{k}\Gamma_j
\end{align}

Under these conditions, it also follows from this definition that there exist a bijective function of class $C^1$, say $\psi_j$, and its inverse such that  *straightens out* $\partial \Omega$ near $x_0$.

Explicitly $\psi_j$ is given by

\begin{align}\tag{18}
\psi_j\colon \Omega_j\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n & \rightarrow \overline{B^{+}_{r}(x_0)}\\
(x_1, ..., x_n)&\mapsto {(x_1, ..., x_{n-1}, x_n -\gamma(x_1, ..., x_{n-1}))}
\end{align}

Thus, we have to show that $\psi_j$ is a bijection of class $C^1$, that is, a diffeomorphism that satisfies the conditions from ${{13}}$ to ${{17}}$. To see this, just consider the change of variables given by

\begin{align}\tag{19}
\psi_j(x):=y
\end{align}

where $x=(x_1, ..., x_n)$ and ${y=(x_1, ..., x_{n-1}, x_n -\gamma(x_1, ..., x_{n-1}) )}$.

We claim that $\psi_j$ is a diffeomorphism.

Indeed, note that considering the change of variables in ${{19}}$ the determinant of Jacobian is
$$
\begin{align*}
|J| &= \det
\begin{pmatrix}\tag{20}
1 & 0 & \dots & -\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial x_1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \dots & \ddots & - \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial x_{n-1}} \\
0 & \dots & 0 & 1- \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial x_{n}} 
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \left( -\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial x_1} - \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial x_2} - \dots - \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial x_{n-1}} \right) \det
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \dots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & \dots & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\\
&= -\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial x_1} - \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial x_2} - \dots - \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial x_{n-1}}\neq 0   
\end{align*}
$$
hence, $\psi_j$ is a diffeomorphism, and the Jacobian $J$ is continuous in $\Omega$ which is bounded, then $|J|_{\psi_j}$ is bounded. Similarly, for $\psi_j^{-1}$, the determinant of Jacobian $|J|_{\psi_j^{-1}}$ is bounded.

From what was exposed in step 1, and the considerations above, we have

\begin{align}\tag{21}
\int_{\Gamma_j} |u|^p d\sigma_x & \stackrel{{{20}}}{=} \int_{\Gamma_j} |u|^p |J|_{\psi_j} d\sigma_y\\
&\stackrel{{{11}}}{\leq} C_j \left(\int_{B_{r}^{+}(x_0)}|\nabla u|^p + |u|^p \right ) |J|_{\psi_j} dy\\
&\stackrel{{20}}{=} C_j \left(\int_{\Omega_j}|\nabla u|^p + |u|^p \right) |J|_{\psi_j^{-1}}dx\\
&\leq C \left(\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^p + |u|^p \right) dx
\end{align}

where in the last inequality we take $C:=\underset{1\leq j\leq n}{\max}\{C_j\}$, where the constant $C_j$ does not depend on $u$. That is, by estimating step 1,

\begin{align}\tag{22}
\|u\|_{L^p(\partial \Omega)}^{p} \stackrel{{19}}{=}&\|u\|_{L^p\left(\mathop{ \bigcup}_{j=1}^{k}\Gamma_j\right)}^{p}\\
\leq &\sum_{j=1}^{k}\|u\|_{L^p(\Gamma_j)}^{p}\\
\stackrel{{12}}{\leq} & \tilde{C} \sum_{j=1}^{k}\|u\|_{W^{1, p}(\Omega)}^ {P}\\
= & \tilde{C} k \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}^{p}
\end{align}

Therefore, considering only the first and last terms in the inequality above, raising both sides to $\frac{1}{p}$ and noting that the constants in steps 1 and 2 depend on $p$ and $k$. Taking $C:=C(k,p)$ we obtain that

\begin{align}\tag{23}
\|u\|_{L^p(\partial \Omega)}\leq C \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}
\end{align}

> **Step 3**

Now defining
\begin{align}
T\colon C^1(\overline{\Omega}) & \rightarrow L^p(\partial\Omega)\\
u &\mapsto Tu\\
\end{align}

so that

\begin{align} \tag{24}
Tu:=u_{|{\partial \Omega}}
\end{align}
So by the inequality in ${{23}}$ we have
\begin{align}\tag{25}
\|Tu\|_{L^p(\partial \Omega)}\leq C \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}
\end{align}
Therefore, the theorem is proven for all $u\in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$.

> **Step 4**

We will use the fact that $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is dense in $C^1{(\overline{\Omega})}$  to construct a unique extension to a continuous linear operator defined in $W ^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

Indeed, let us suppose that $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, then there exists a sequence of functions $(u_m)\in C^{1}(\overline{\Omega})$ such that
$$u_m \rightarrow u \in  W^{1,p}(\Omega).$$
It follows from the inequality in ${{25}}$ that

\begin{align} \tag{26}
\|T (u_m - u_l)\|_{L^{p}(\partial \Omega)}&\leq C \|u_m-u_l\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}
\end{align}

thus $\{Tu_m\}_{m\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^{p}(\partial \Omega)$ which is complete space, therefore it is a convergent sequence with $\lim_{m\to \infty} Tu_m \in L^{p}(\partial \Omega)$.

We define it like this

\begin{align}\tag{27}
Tu := \underset{m\to \infty}{\lim} Tu_m
\end{align}

as being the limit reached in $L^p(\partial \Omega)$. Note that $Tu$ does not depend on the choice of sequences $(u_m)$. To see this, consider that there exists other $v_m\in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ such that $v_m\rightarrow u$ and thus by ${{25}}$

\begin{align}    
        \|Tv_m - Tu_m\|_{L^p(\partial \Omega)}\leq &C \|v_m-u_m\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}\\
        \leq & C {\|v_m -u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}+\|u_m -u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}}    
\end{align}

taking the limit $m\rightarrow \infty$ then we obtain that

\begin{align}
    Tv_m\equiv Tu_m
\end{align}

So ${{26}}$ it is well defined, linear and limited.

Finally, if $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega})$, it follows that $(u_m)$ converges uniformly to $u$ on compact subsets of $\overline{\Omega}$, in particular over $\partial \Omega$, this is

\begin{align}
    u_{|{\partial \Omega}} =Tu =T\left(\lim_{m\to \infty} u_m \right) = \lim_{m\to \infty} Tu_m
\end{align}

Therefore, $(Tu_m)$ converges uniformly to $u_{|{\partial \Omega}}$ over $\partial \Omega$, this convergence uniform comes from results of real analysis in several variables.

Comment: $U$ is given by the definition of $\Omega$ being $C^1$. I believe (18) is right. There are some grammar errors (e.g. "Choose" instead of "Choice") and there is a lot of extra space where it's not needed (e.g. `|p\;{\mathrm{sgn}}(u)\; \varphi u_{x_n}\;|`$|p\;{\mathrm{sgn}}(u)\; \varphi u_{x_n}\;| $ should be `|p\operatorname{sign}(u)\varphi u_{x_n}|` $|p\operatorname{sgn}(u)\varphi u_{x_n}|$ and  `|u_{x_n}\;|`$|u_{x_n}\;| $ should be `|u_{x_n}|`$|u_{x_n}|$)

Comment: in (21), the sum should be up to $k$, not $n$. (its not important, but you don't need to have the constant $k$ come up because there should not be a lot of overlap in the cover). Also suggestions for the diagram: IMO, there isn't a need for the arrow pointing to the label for $\Gamma$ since the red colour already tells me what $Gamma$ is; and I think the diagram later for $B^+_r$ should only have the upper half coloured blue

Comment: Yes, step 4 is right

Comment: Hi @CalvinKhor I am here to thank you for your help. Today I fulfilled everything I think you advised. I hope that now is everything better than before. Blessed 2024 for us!